# DoubleAnimation with Margin

Tags: c#, wpf

How could I animate a usercontrol's margin? I want to do this directly in Window background code. That's what I have:

```
addServer = new AddServer();
addServer.Height = 300;
addServer.Width = 570;

// 252, 248, 26, 0
addServer.Margin = new Thickness(252, 550, 26, 0);
Main.Children.Add(addServer);

DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
doubleAnimation.From = 550;
doubleAnimation.To = 248;
doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation, addServer.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(addServer.Margin));
```

AddServer is the UserControl I want to animate. Want I want to achieve is a fly in animation.

Comment: Use a ThicknessAnimation instead of DoubleAnimation.

Comment: To animate things like `Margin` you use [`ThicknesAnimation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh, cool thanks for the point. Didn't knew about ThicknessAnimation.